# Issue reading and printing ip header ID in c

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

so I am having trouble dissecting an IPV4 header. In particularly I am having trouble reading the ID portion.

I am following this image.
[IPV4Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZjMn.png)

And I am reading the entire ipv4 packet using fread and storing it into an array of chars like so

```
     unsigned char buffer[2048] = "";
     fread(buffer, 1, 20, file);
```

Now according to that image the ID should be the 5th and 6th byte.

So I try to store it into an unsigned char and print like so

```
unsigned char id = buffer[4] + buffer[5]
printf("Identification: 0x%X (%d)\n", id, id);
```

But I am getting the wrong value. And I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am reading incorrectly several other parts of the header as well, hopefully figuring this out will help me figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID is two bytes in length, so you have to use an integer type large enough to hold both bytes. Adding them together doesn't achieve the same result.

```
unsigned short id = (buffer[4] << 8) | buffer[5];
printf("Identification: 0x%hx (%hu)\n", id, id);
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped!